# Calculating fields through trigger in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables `product` and `shop`
I have a trigger that works when a product is added to shop, then it updates the `product quantity` from Shop when inserted and `total price` from the fields of Product quantity and unit price. 
The Quantity is updated correctly.

The problem is: the `total price` is not updated correctly. What is the problem?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UpdtProQty]

ON [dbo].[Shop] FOR Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    -- update Product quantity and total price from shop table
    UPDATE pd
    SET pd.qty = pd.qty-i.qty, pd.tprice=pd.uprice*pd.qty
    FROM dbo.Product pd
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON pd.pid = i.pid        
END
```

Comment: You are updating TotalPrice only based on the <Price and Quantity> in your Product table but in your comment you write 'and total price from shop table'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates do not happen in the order you write them in, i.e. in your original update statement you have:

```
SET pd.qty = pd.qty-i.qty, 
    pd.tprice=pd.uprice*pd.qty
```

When you are setting `tprice` the value of `pd.qty` is still the original value, this should be

```
SET pd.qty = pd.qty-i.qty, 
    pd.tprice=pd.uprice*(pd.qty-i.qty)
```

If `tprice` is such a simple calculation , you may want to not bother storing it at all, and simply use a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product DROP COLUMN tprice;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Product ADD tprice AS uprice * Qty;
```

Then you wouldn't have to worry about keeping it up to date, it would automatically refresh whenever the quantity or price changed.

---

**ADDENDUM**

In order to capture updates to the shop table, you would need to make your trigger for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, you would then need to reference the memory resident table `deleted` in your trigger to find out what the actual change is, given by `deleted.qty - inserted.qty`, so your trigger would end up something like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_UpdtProQty]
ON [dbo].[Shop] FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- update Product quantity and total price from shop table
    UPDATE pd
    SET     pd.qty = pd.qty + (ISNULL(d.qty, 0) - i.qty), 
            pd.tprice = pd.uprice * (pd.qty + (ISNULL(d.qty, 0) - i.qty))
    FROM    dbo.Product pd
            INNER JOIN Inserted i 
                ON pd.pid = i.pid        
            LEFT JOIN Deleted d
                ON d.pid = pd.pid;
END
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful tip.

Comment: I have one issue. When I update the shop quantity for instance from 5 to 3, then the product Quantity should be incremented. Because when we add product to shop we are decreasing, in another hand when the shop product is updated to down, the product quantity should be incremented. So is there any solution to the existing query to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

When you update record should not getting updated value at time.
so you can do this

```
UPDATE pd
    SET pd.qty = pd.qty-i.qty, pd.tprice=pd.uprice*(pd.qty-i.qty)
    FROM dbo.Product pd
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON pd.pid = i.pid
```

Comment: Your solution is works. But I have one issue. When I update the shop quantity for instance from 5 to 3, then the product Quantity should be incremented, so how can fix that problem?